# Azure Open AI InvalidRequestError

Tags: azure-openai

I'm new to OpenAI and trying some calls. I have created the resources and got my project endpoint and api key. However, I got the following error:

InvalidRequestError: The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again.

I saw some comments online that I might need to create deployment in Azure AI Studio. I first tried with 'text-embedding-ada-002' but it doesn't work. Then I add another deployment using 'gpt-35-turbo' but still get the same error. Both deployment has the status 'Succeeded'